# Apache POI+OOXML memory usage

Tags: kotlin, jvm, apache-poi

I'm currently working on a Kotlin + JVM project, where we have an Excel file which we use as "source of information".

In order to parse this file and create our own objects we are using "apache.poi+poi-ooxml
version: 5.2.4".

Recently we started to have some JavaHeapSpace issues. We ran some Java profiles and we realised that those Objects "org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.AttrXobj/org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.ElementXobj" are taking a lot of memory:

[image]

The Excel file has around 2.9MB and we have a node with around 4GB dedicated to Java.

I know that pretty much hard to tell from outside what the problem is, but perhaps someone could have a hint about what we could do to reduce the usage of those objects.

Thanks,

Comment: Use the event model to read in, rather than the DOM-based usermodel?